# The continuity of the the stable and unstable in definition of hyperbolic sets for flows

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds, symbolic-dynamics, hyperbolic-dynamics

I would like to know whether the continuity of the stable and unstable subbundles $E^{s}$ and $E^{u}$ follows from the growth conditions as in the discrete case, or must be hypothesized, in the definitions of hyperbolic sets for flows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it follows from the growth conditions. It should be done in standard texts (e.g. Katok-Hasselblatt) but I have not checked. Indeed, it is a general fact about [dominated splittings](http://www.cmat.edu.uy/%7Erpotrie/documentos/pdfs/Crovisier-Potrie-PH.pdf).

In fact, the growth conditions provide a gap in the singular values of the map and this forces the existence of a continuous splitting. See for example this paper by [Bochi and Gourmelon](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.3811) (see also section 2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01742) where it is explicitly stated for flows).